# Resize div using values assigned to variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a select menu with 3 options. Using a `.change` function I've set 3 variables which has the width of a div. How can I refer the select menu VALUE to a variable inside the `.change` function to pass a new width value?

Example: if Taffy is selected, I need the width of `$('#newDIV")` to be `$('#dv1').width() * 0.35`

```
<select name="sweets">
  <option value="a">Chocolate</option>
  <option value="b">Taffy</option>
  <option value="c">Fudge</option>
</select>

$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var a = $('#dv1').width() * 0.9;
    var b = $('#dv1').width() * 0.35;
    var c = $('#dv1').width() * 0.2;

   $('#newDIV").width( $(this).val() + 'px'); //outputs 'bpx' ?
})
```

Please suggest if there is a better way of achieving this.

Comment: Keep that value in span and dont give any width..

Comment: @RayonDabre thanks but doesn't make any sense to me?

Comment: @madalinivascu thanks but I'm afraid that wouldn't work. coz `b` should come from the select value not by typing there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRy:

```
<select name="sweets">
      <option value="0.9">Chocolate</option>
      <option value="0.35">Taffy</option>
      <option value="0.2">Fudge</option>
    </select>

    $( "select" ).change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val()? parseFloat($(this).val()) :1,
        a = $('#dv1').width() * val;
       $('#newDIV').width(a); 
    })
```

Comment: Like your approach. Few suggestions:  1. use `parseFloat` to the `val` 2. Syntax Error 3. No need of `px` in `width` 4. Make sure `val` is present, use 1 otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("select").on('change', function() {
    var divWidth = $('#dv1').width();

    var newWidth;

    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 'a':
            newWidth = divWidth * 0.9;
            break;
        case 'b':
            newWidth = divWidth * 0.35;
            break;
        case 'c':
            newWidth = divWidth * 0.2;
            break;
        default:
            // Set default width here

    }

    $('#newDIV').width(newWidth);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2szymspp/

Comment: that's good do you think your answer is better than madalin ivascu? Not a comparison but getting to know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @Becky I've answered by assuming that your HTML will not change, but if you can change your HTML then you should use the Mandalin's approach

Answer (score 0):

Have a conditional statement. Do something like this :

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  if(selectedVal == 'a')
    var newWidth = $('#dv1').width() * 0.9;
  else if(selectedVal == 'b')
    var newWidth = $('#dv1').width() * 0.35;
  else if(selectedVal == 'c')
    var newWidth = $('#dv1').width() * 0.2;

   $("#newDIV").width( newWidth + 'px'); //outputs 'bpx' ?
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the selected option and apply a switch case to it.

```
$( "select" ).change(function () {
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    switch(selectedValue) {
        case 'a':
            $('#dv1').width() * 0.9;
            break;
        case 'b':
            $('#dv1').width() * 0.35;
            break;
        case 'c':
            $('#dv1').width() * 0.2;
            break;                     
    }
   $('#newDIV').width( $(this).val() + 'px'); //outputs 'bpx' ?
})
```

Comment: thanks but I think there is an answer already similar to this.

Comment: @Becky By the time I was posting this answer, similar answers have been posted. I was late :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("select").on("change", function()
  {
    var widthFactor = 0.5;
    var strLen = $(this).find("option:selected").html().length;
    var myWidth = (strLen * widthFactor) + 'px';
    $("yourSelector").css("width", myWidth)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

And of course, the vanilla javascript option for future viewers

```
<select name="sweets">
    <option value="0.9">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="0.35">Taffy</option>
    <option value="0.2">Fudge</option>
</select>

(function () {
    "use strict"
    var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select'), select,
        dv1 = document.getElementById('dv1'),
        newDiv = document.getElementById('newDiv');
    for (var i = 0; select = selects[i]; i++) {
        select.addEventListener('change',function(){
            var val = this.value ? parseFloat(this.value) : 1;
            var a = dv1.scrollWidth * val;
            newDiv.width(a);
        },false);
    }
})();
```